# How to do a pointer to a function in a class

Tags: ios, objective-c, function, pointers, methods

I've been trying to do an ios app with:

- a viewcontrolloer with some functions/methods
- a new class with a pointer to these functions/methods so that class1.point2f () would work

  ```
  // testclass header
  @property void (*point2f)();


  // viewcontroller header        
  #import "testclass.h"

  @interface ViewController : UIViewController
  {
      testclass *test;
  }

  @property testclass *test;

  @end


  // viewcontroller implementation
  void downx() 
  {
      NSLog(@"hello");
  };

  - (void)viewDidLoad
  {
      [super viewDidLoad];

      test.point2f = downx;

      test.point2f ();     // crashes only at this line
  ```

I would be very thankfull for answers or at least keywords I could look into further.

Comment: did you create an instance of the testclass like `self.test = [[testclass alloc] init];`

Comment: @picciano not even close. This is asking about storing a c-function pointer in an objc class, that is asking about selectors.

Comment: Thank you @Ahmed! Works now. Finally :) !

Comment: you're welcome. I didn't see you comment. So I posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to call a NULL function pointer. In objective-c, instance variables are initialized to nil (NULL). So the variable `test` is nil. It is not an error to access a property of a nil pointer but that does not do anything. Therefore, `test.point2f = downx;` does nothing and `test` is still nil. Every property of a nil pointer also returns nil (0, NO etc..). So `test.point2f` is actually nil. So effectively what you're doing is

```
((void (*)())NULL) ();    // dereferencing a NULL pointer
```

You need to instantiate a `testclass` object and assign it to `test` before accessing any of it's properties.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.test = [[testclass alloc] init];
    test.point2f = downx;
    test.point2f();     // won't crash anymore

    // rest of your code
}
```